# Give me persons who own all of the given cars

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need a single Cypher query where I need to get all persons who own all of the given cars

For example

```
Person 1 -> Car 1
Person 1 -> Car 2
Person 1 -> Car 3

Person 2 -> Car 2
Person 2 -> Car 3
Person 2 -> Car 4

Person 3 -> Car 3
Person 3 -> Car 4
Person 3 -> Car 5

If the input is Car 2, Car 3, then the output should be Person 1, Person 2
If the input is Car 3, Car 4, then the output should be Person 2, Person 3
If the input is Car 3, Car 4, Car 5 then the output should be Person 3
If the input is Car 1, Car 3, Car 5 then the output should be Empty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a knowledge base article on [performing match intersection](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/performing-match-intersection/) which addresses these kinds of queries.

Using the first approach in the article, we need to perform pattern match given the input (persons who own the given cars), then count the number of cars from that set that were matched per person, then compare that to the number of cars in the input list, and where those counts match then you've found your person:

```
WITH ['Car 3', 'Car 4'] as cars
MATCH (p:Person)-[:OWNS]->(c:Car)
WHERE c.name in cars
WITH p, size(cars) as inputCnt, count(DISTINCT c) as cnt
WHERE cnt = inputCnt
RETURN p
```

You should have an index on :Car(name) for this so the query can use an index lookup to find the starting :Car nodes quick.